# Trying to use CASE WHEN inside CASE WHEN mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql

Look at my code, i want to achieve something like that when cat='1' then CASE or when cat='2', then CASE. Help, appreciate.

```html
<?php
$test ="SELECT DISTINCT dis from $table WHERE 
              ( 
              CASE When cat='1' THEN (CASE  
                      WHEN val2 ='g' THEN val1 > %d
        WHEN val2 ='l' THEN val1 < %d
        ELSE val1 !=%d END) 
     
               When cat='2' THEN (CASE  
                      WHEN val2 ='g' THEN val1 > %d
        WHEN val2 ='l' THEN val1 < %d
        ELSE val1 !=%d END)
              ELSE END
               )
      AND dis IN ('19','20','21')
      ";
?>
```

Comment: it looks like you are just missing the outer `WHEN`'s `THEN`s. (Ex: `WHEN cat='1' THEN (CASE....`). ... and you need an outer `CASE` for those `WHEN`s as well... and no `OR`

Comment: So, what happens? Error (post) or wrong results (post some data and expected results and what you actually get). There shouldn't be a problem with layered CASE statements - in native MySQL or PHP.

Comment: just echo nothing, see no error, if I do one by one, it is OK, if I combine these two case together, then echo nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try it in one `CASE` statement and see if it returns the expected results:

```
<?php
$test ="SELECT DISTINCT dis from $table 
WHERE CASE 
WHEN cat='1' AND val2 ='g' THEN val1 > %d
WHEN cat='1' AND val2 ='l' THEN val1 < %d
WHEN cat='1' THEN val1 !=%d
WHEN cat='2' AND val2 ='g' THEN val1 > %d
WHEN cat='2' AND val2 ='l' THEN val1 < %d
WHEN cat='2' THEN val1 !=%d
END
AND dis IN ('19','20','21')
";
?>
```

Also, it doesn't look like there is any difference depending on whether the `cat = 1 or 2`, so you could possibly reduce the `CASE` to:

```
CASE 
WHEN cat in ('1','2') AND val2 ='g' THEN val1 > %d
WHEN cat in ('1','2') AND val2 ='l' THEN val1 < %d
WHEN cat in ('1','2') THEN val1 !=%d
END
```